# airflow.exceptions.SerializedDagNotFound --> Scheduler down?

Tags: docker, airflow, amazon-ecs, airflow-scheduler

I run `Airflow 2.1.2` in `AWS ECS` using `docker`.

My scheduler shows Error log such as:

```
 airflow.exceptions.SerializedDagNotFound
```

Checking in the `dag` table in the database, the dag that this error shows has `active=False` but `is_paused=False`.

I found 4 dags that had these same behavior. All of them weren't in the UI.

The ones that are in the ACTIVE view of the UI have:

`active=True`  `is_paused=False`

The ones in the PAUSED view have:

`active=True`  `is_paused=True`

So I assume that `ON/OFF` button in the `UI` mark the dag as paused in the `DB`. So maybe we didn't stop the dag that returns the  `airflow.exceptions.SerializedDagNotFound` error, and scheduler tried to schedule it but file is not there anymore. Does it makes sense?

Could be this the reason of the scheduler went down? If I filter `"ERROR"` on `cloudwatch` these are the only logs that I found, and scheduler is not always down after these `ERROR`.

I would like to understand what's the difference between active and paused and how to modify it in the `DB` from `UI`.

To provide some more context:

We were using `1.10.15` and `Airflow` was stable there and these dags were running there, never saw `Scheduler` down in one year. We migrate `Airflow` version and issues started to raise.

Comment: Running Airflow 2.1.4 we see this behaviour too.
The scheduler seems to be in a death loop after a while, but does not stop working so that the container is also not restarted.

Comment: @flymg I deleted the rows that create that trouble and after that the error was not shown anymore.

Comment: mrc which table have you used?